# How to create database design with dummy data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, erd

I often create MySQL ERD (database design/diagram) using mysql workbench or any other online db designer tools. but, i have usual problem when i started to design database for my project. let's say i want to create this:

```
tbl_user
id | int, Auto increment, primary key
user | varchar(100)
password | varchar(255) => password as base64
```

sometimes i want to insert dummy data on that table to make sure i dont make any mistake / forgot about what kind of data that i must insert in to those columns.

```
id | user | password
1 | admin | YWRtaW4= (base64: admin)
```

let's say when i first time think is the password will used base64 encode. and i want to create dummy data to prevent me insert password as plain password, md5 or sha-1

so what i want is application that can generate table from my ERD and insert my dummy data when i generate it into mysql scheme

i try so many online tools , dbdesigner and workbench, but there is no way to do this. what i can is only using note/comment to my table

i will appreciate any help.
thanks

NOTE: absolutely i wont use base64 as password. this is just simple example case

Comment: so are you just looking to insert dummy data into the database?

Comment: both of create diagram and insert several data

Comment: btw. after i try several apps. i find that phpmyadmin is the closest match for my need. he can create diagram, insert several data. and after that i can export into sql script

Comment: i dont know of a program that will do both. But i have used http://www.generatedata.com/#about before and that will create you the insert scripts you can copy onto your server

Comment: my several friend suggest me similar tools like that (generate dummy data). 1. i need create diagram to visualize my structure (ERD). 2. i need to insert certain data (not dummy). example: tbl_user have id,name and id_gender. tbl_gender have id and type. i need to insert explisit/certain/fixed data in tbl_gender which is male and female. i hope you undestand. sry for my english. i very appreciate your help. thanks, phpmyadmin already solved my problem

Comment: additional: why i need insert data? to prevent me to insert "m", "f" or "1","2" instead "male","female" in tbl_gender

Comment: how did phpmyadmin solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely have a go with Devart's dbForge...It supports ERD design with implementation (similar with Workbench), reverse engineering from DB to ERD, data generator with over 200 predefinite sintaxes but also offer the possibility to create your own data based on your own defined rules...